# Display .csv content in the same format on any website

Tags: csv, ubuntu, opencart, vps

I am not sure how to describe the problem I am facing, but I will try to do that as short as possible.

I am trying to synchronize vendor stock with my shop. I have extension installed which can reach and synchronize files from any other website, but the format of content should be .xml or .csv

So, I get the file from vendor in .csv format, however I do not know how to upload or make that .csv file readable for my extension. If I upload the .csv file directly to my website - when I enter it on the browser it automatically downloads without showing any content. The extension behaves the same and cannot read information from the file.

So, to solve the problem I need to do something that .csv files will be visible on the browser instead of autodownloading them. I was reading the forum about headers and something like that, but I do not know where to change anything and what to do with these headers.

I hope I described the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Found a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
You should parse csv file:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Pay attention which delimiter of the columns is used. In this example comma is used `$handle, 1000, ","`